# How to execute cURL URL from PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to call a URL from PHP via cURL, but no response from server.

Following is my URL:

```
$url = 'https://id:secret@auth.sphere.io/oauth/token \ -X POST \ -d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=manage_project:test"';
```

Curl code:

```
$auth = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($auth, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($auth, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($auth, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($auth);
curl_close($auth);
print_r($response);
```

When I execute the same URL in terminal get response from server. What's wrong in cURL code?

Comment: The URL does not look right = seems to be the command line options to curl

Comment: `CURL` is installed in your web server, right?

Comment: Yes, curl is installed

Comment: I don't see the data parameter in your code

Comment: @AkkapongKajornwongwattana  what data parameter??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the documentation - this should work. Note the correct URL and passing the post parameters correctly

```
$auth = curl_init("https://auth.sphere.io/oauth/token");
curl_setopt($auth, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($auth, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($auth, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($auth,CURLOPT_POST, 2);
curl_setopt($auth,CURLOPT_USERPWD, "id:secret");
curl_setopt($auth,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=manage_project:test");
$response = curl_exec($auth);
curl_close($auth);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: Tried. Getting `Missing required parameter: grant_type` error.

Comment: Is that a response from the server?

Comment: still same . `{"statusCode":400,"message":"Missing required parameter: grant_type.","errors":[{"code":"invalid_request","message":"Missing required parameter: grant_type."}],"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing required parameter: grant_type."}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136508/discussion-between-gowri-and-ed-heal).

Comment: Just noticed that I made an error in the cut'n'paste

Answer (score 3):

Check the Curl Snippet

```
 $auth = curl_init("https://id:secret@auth.sphere.io/oauth/token");
    curl_setopt($auth, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($auth, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($auth, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($auth,CURLOPT_POST, 2);
    curl_setopt($auth,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=manage_project:test");
    $response = curl_exec($auth);
    curl_close($auth);
    print_r($response);
```

provide the correct credentials in order for the authentication to be successful

Answer (score 1):

@Ed Heal - modifying your code following should work

```
$auth = curl_init("https://auth.sphere.io/oauth/token");
curl_setopt($auth, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($auth, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($auth, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($auth,CURLOPT_POST, 2);
curl_setopt($auth,CURLOPT_USERPWD, "id:secret");
curl_setopt($auth,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=manage_project:test");
$response = curl_exec($auth);
curl_close($auth);
print_r($response);
```

$ch is problem as curl is initialize with $auth